# The given data was invalid "Requested quantity is not available.", NextJS and Commerce JS

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments

Hi guys i'm creating an e-commerce with CommerceJs and NextJS when handling payment i get this error

message: "The given data was invalid."
type: "unprocessable_entity"
line_items.item_7RyWOwmK5nEa2V.quantity: ["Requested quantity is not available."]

i tried to change my code like the docs but no luck

```
const orderData = {
    line_items: {
      item_7RyWOwmK5nEa2V: {
        quantity: 1,
      }
    },
    customer: {
      firstname: 'John',
      lastname: 'Doe',
      email: 'john.doe@example.com'
    },
    shipping: {
      name: 'John Doe',
      street: '123 Fake St',
      town_city: 'San Francisco',
      county_state: 'US-CA',
      postal_zip_code: '94103',
      country: 'US'
    },
    fulfillment: {
      shipping_method: 'ship_7RyWOwmK5nEa2V'
    },
    billing: {
      name: 'John Doe',
      street: '234 Fake St',
      town_city: 'San Francisco',
      county_state: 'US-CA',
      postal_zip_code: '94103',
      country: 'US'
    },
    payment: {
      gateway: 'stripe',
      stripe: {
        payment_method_id: paymentMethod.id,
      },
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must go into your commerce.js dashboard and edit the available quantity of your product there. You will see it under dashboard > products > productName > inventoryAvailable. Be sure to also check if you have variants, that the selected variant has an available inventory to draw from as well...

You can use this code to test if your product inventory is available...

```
commerce.checkout.checkQuantity("your-checkout-token", 'item-id', {
    amount: 1,
    variant_id: 'your-variant-id-OPTIONAL'
}).then((response) => console.log(response.available));
```